# Stop ajax listener from sending empty parameter to function

Tags: ajax

I have a number of functions that do a live ajax check on some fields; for example, a couple of seconds after the `email` field is filled out, it fires an ajax check to see if that email is already being used by another account. I also want to use the same function for double-checking the values posted to the form overall. At the moment, it looks like something like this:

```
function ajax_checkEmailAddress($passedEmail = false) {

    $isAjaxRequest = ($passedEmail === false);

    $sentEmail = (!$isAjaxRequest) ? $passedEmail : sanitize_email($_POST['email'], true);

    if (email_exists($sentEmail)) {
    $jsonArray['response'] = 'error';
    $jsonArray['message'] = __('This email address is already in use.', 'ajaxSignup');
    } else {
        $jsonArray['response'] = 'success';
    }

    if ($isAjaxRequest) {
        wp_send_json($jsonArray);
    } else {
        return $jsonArray;
    }
}
```

I subsequently have another ajax function that deals with processing the complete submitted form:

```
function ajax_processForm() {

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $checkedEmail = ajax_checkEmailAddress($email);

    if ($checkedEmail['response'] == 'success') {
        //  Continue processing the form actions
    } else {
        wp_send_json($checkedEmail);
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_processForm', 'ajax_processForm');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_processForm', 'ajax_processForm');
```

I don't want to double up on all of my error-checking functions, hence the use of the `$passedEmail` parameter check, which defaults to `false`; that way the function should know whether it's being called by ajax or by an internal function, and can `return` the results array to the function instead of `wp_send_json`, which would `die()`.

However, using standard ajax listeners:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_checkEmailAddress', 'ajax_checkEmailAddress');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_checkEmailAddress', 'ajax_checkEmailAddress');
```

...they always seem to send an empty parameter, so `$passedEmail` never defaults to `false`. Even if I try to default it with nonsense, it gets overwritten:

```
function ajax_checkEmailAddress($passedEmail = 'wibble') {
    wp_send_json($passedEmail); //  Returns '' when called via ajax
}
```

Unfortunately I can't use `DOING_AJAX` to determine whether the field-check function should `return` or `wp_send_json`, because the form-check function itself is called via ajax, so `DOING_AJAX` always returns `true`.

I have half a dozen of these 'live check' functions for different field types, so I *really* don't want to duplicate them all. Is there any way for `wp_ajax` to *not* send an empty parameter? Or a neater way of dealing with this?

It sounds *similar* to the issue that was raised in [this old trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20699), but it's not exactly the same, and that only discussed rolling it back between 3.4 & 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just abstracting the actual validation to another function:

```
function ajax_checkEmailAddress($passedEmail = false) {

    $sentEmail = sanitize_email($_POST['email'], true);

    $jsonArray = validateEmailAddress($passedEmail);
    wp_send_json($jsonArray);

}

add_action('wp_ajax_checkEmailAddress', 'ajax_checkEmailAddress');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_checkEmailAddress', 'ajax_checkEmailAddress');

function validateEmailAddress($email) {
    if (email_exists($email)) {
        $jsonArray['response'] = 'error';
        $jsonArray['message'] = __('This email address is already in use.', 'ajaxSignup');
    } else {
        $jsonArray['response'] = 'success';
    }

    return $jsonArray;
}
```

This way, `validateEmailAddress` can be called from another PHP function without issue, and the ajax function doesn't have to try to decipher if it's actually a *direct* ajax call or not.

I still have no idea as to why `wp_ajax` sends an empty parameter, but I would be intrigued to know.